# Large IRQ value in windows for MSI

Tags: windows, device-driver, interrupt

For [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Signaled_Interrupts)(Message Signaled Interrupts), [the IRQ value in the Windows Device Manager is large or negative](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/winservergen/thread/e43c2c97-6e87-40c9-81f2-d1de219fb55b).

Why is this so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking "why", the answer is "because that's what Microsoft decided to do".

Message Signaled Interrupt support was added in Windows Vista: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463217.aspx

When a device is configured for MSI, the IRQ number is negative: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940394

As a side effect of it being a negative number, it may appear as something like 0xFFFFFFFFC, depending on how the program decides to display the IRQ info. (Read up on [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) if you don't know why this happens.)

As to ***why*** Microsoft chose to represent an MSI as a negative number, my guess is that this was done to clearly differentiate them from traditional "wired" interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your question. In given link is all explained. For MSI is IRQ assigned large positive or small negative value, because is not true IRQ. Also this value is same, because conversion between signed and unsigned dwords. :-)